# Rspec fields in context scope

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-1.9

Didn't really know how to phrase the title but my problem is as follows:

```
shared_examples "something" do 
  context "for something" do 
    fields.each do |field| 
      it "should have #{field} field" do 
        #Check something 
      end
    end
  end
end

describe Clazz do
  it_behaves_like "something" do
    let(:fields) {%w{something something2}}
  end
end
```

The execution of course blows up in the `fields.each` part since the variables are introduced in the `it` scope, not in `context`.

So my question is how would I introduce variables with to it_behaves_like to the context scope? Or should I use something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about `shared_examples`, but if you use [`shared_examples_for`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group) you can pass arguments to the block, like so:

```
shared_examples_for "something" do |fields|
  context "for something" do
    fields.each do |field| 
      it "should have #{field} field" do 
        #Check something 
      end
    end
  end
end

describe Clazz do
  it_behaves_like "something", %w{something something2}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

shared_examples already creates a new context, so I think the cleanest way would be like shioyama's example without the extra context:

```
shared_examples_for "something" do |fields|
  fields.each do |field| 
    it "should have #{field} field" do 
      # specify something
    end
  end
end

describe Clazz do
  it_behaves_like "something", %w{something something2}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let is evaluated before each `it` block but not for `context` or `describe` as far as I'm aware of.

```
describe "something" do 
  let(:fields) { %w{something something2} }

  it "should have all fields" do 
    fields.each do |field| 
    end
  end
end
```